# Search and Update respective data using jsp,servlet,mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

```
Hello,
           My Scenario is like thse-
I have one textbox ,in which when user type the project names then list of projects appear and user select one from the list.
```

I have also one button to update the selected project details.
Now I want when user click on the Edit button then next jsp page should appear,and the previously selected project details should filled automatically in the textbox and now user can update the data.
I am not getting how to implement these using jsp,servlet and mysql.
 I want to update only drop down box values,and other textbox fields should be uneditable.

```
 <input id="name" type="text" name="ProjName"  placeholder="Search Project name"onkeyup="showState(this.value)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Display" style="margin-left: 0%;width:80px;height:32px;background-color:#007BC0;color:white" onclick="form.action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/SearchProject';"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Edit" style="margin-left: 0%;width:80px;height:32px;background-color:#007BC0;color:white" onclick="form.action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/EditProj.jsp';" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left: 0%;width:80px;height:32px;background-color:#007BC0;color:white" onclick="form.action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/DeleteProject';" />
```

Above is the code for textbox and button.On click of Edit button EditProj.jsp page should appear .EditProj.jsp page is containing some textbox and drop down box.Please help me ,How Can I implement these scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, will do as like following mentioned points.I don't know about your DB processes.

1. When click edit button fetch the data from DB base on your input ( I guess 'project name')
2. Show relevant data on your  EditProj.jsp ( Set your attributes in request and forward your request to jsp from servlet).

You can use disable property for your purpose. Otherwise just print the values under `<p>`tag.

Hope this may help for you. Thanks!